# How does increasing the battery voltage affect the power delivered to a light globe in a single light globe circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power, batteries

I am doing a prac in my physics class and I would like to know how does increasing the battery voltage affect the power delivered to a light globe in a single light globe circuit?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complicated. If the resistance of the bulb did not change, it would be a simple case of $P=V^2/R$. In other words, the power delivered to the bulb would go up with the square of the voltage. That is also why, as you increase the voltage, a bulb gets brighter, until the filament eventually gets so hot that it melts, and the lamp burns out.

For a simple filament bulb, the problem is that the resistance of the bulb depends on the bulb. The resistance of the wire goes up as the temperature increases. Hence it will not get as bright as you would expect. However, while the power increases with the square of the voltage, the [resistance only increases approximately linearly](http://physics.usask.ca/~bzulkosk/Lab_Manuals/EP354/ep354_thermal-radiation-lab_Tungsten-Temp-Resistivity.pdf) with the temperature. As a result, it will still get brighter and will still burn out.

For other types of bulbs, there are other issues. With LED bulbs, the electronic circuit that drives the LEDs keeps the voltage to the LEDs constant. If the input voltage gets too high, the electronics may fail, or a fail-safe circuit may switch it off until the voltage is reduced to normal. The failure mode determines what happens to the bulb itself.

Halogen bulbs are fancy filament bulbs, and behave in the same way as ordinary bulbs. However, they are normally supplied by some kind of transformer. If that is an electronic down-converter, then the same issues apply as with LEDs: it may have enough smarts to take care of over-voltage, or it may fail.